# Disable mail environment approvers

Tags: azure, azure-devops, devops

When deploying to an environment in Azure Devops I set some people to approve a deployment. At least one person must approve the deployments to tst, & uat. two to prd. When deploying all people get a mail, because it is often a person that can approve that oversees the deployment this is not needed. I would like to have that there will be no mails or notifications for the tst & uat environment, only for the prd. Is this possible, I could not find a solution. thx

Answer (score 0):

We can create email notification in Azure Devops , and we can custom email setting to whom we want to send .

Based on the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/notifications/manage-team-group-global-organization-notifications?view=azure-devops&tabs=new-account-enabled#create-an-email-subscription):
Choose which team members should receive a notification:

[image: Screenshot of Deliver to and Roles dropdown menus.]

For more information please refer this Microsoft documentation :  [Define approvals and checks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/approvals?view=azure-devops&tabs=check-pass)